# having trouble installing openCV using Homebrew

Tags: python, opencv, homebrew

I'm runing mac os x mavericks and I'm trying to install openCV using Homebrew I'm not sure how to fix it should I unistall Homebrew and python and try again if so how can I unistall them

first I did this 
***ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"*** 
then this
***brew tap homebrew/science***
which is worked cuz when I typed ***brew tap homebrew/science*** again  I got ***Warning: Already tapped!***

but when I type ***brew info opencv*** I got this error 
***Error: No available formula for opencv*** 
and when I tried brew *install opencv* it shows this

```
Searching formulae...
Searching taps...
mymac:~ user$
```

this is what I got when I run brew doctor

```
Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers
with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is
working fine: please don't worry and just ignore them. Thanks!

Warning: Python is installed at /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework

Homebrew only supports building against the System-provided Python or a
brewed Python. In particular, Pythons installed to /Library can interfere
with other software installs.

Warning: /usr/bin occurs before /usr/local/bin
This means that system-provided programs will be used instead of those
provided by Homebrew. The following tools exist at both paths:

    2to3
    2to3-2.7
    idle
    idle2.7
    pydoc
    pydoc2.7
    python
    python-config
    python2.7
    python2.7-config
    pythonw
    pythonw2.7
    smtpd.py
    smtpd2.7.py

Consider setting your PATH so that /usr/local/bin
occurs before /usr/bin. Here is a one-liner:
    echo export PATH='/usr/local/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bash_profile

Warning: Your Xcode (6.0.1) is outdated
Please update to Xcode 6.1.
Xcode can be updated from the App Store.
```

## **UPDATE** 1

I fixed my problem I decided to post it just in case someone came across the same issue 
this is what I did

```
untap homebrew/science
brew update
brew doctor 
brew tap homebrew/science
```

Comment: Try building it from the source.

Comment: @Ryan how to build from source

Answer (score 1):

This is my procedure for installing on linux. It's worked robustly for me in the past:

1. Download OpenCV 2.4.9 from http://opencv.org/downloads.html for Linux/Mac OS and extract.
2. In terminal, navigate to the newly extracted directory and make a new dir called `build` with `mkdir build` in the terminal. Then `cd` to `build`
3. Now, in the terminal, enter:

> cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local
>   -D WITH_TBB=ON -D BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON -D WITH_V4L=ON -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON -D
>   BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON -D WITH_QT=ON -D WITH_OPENGL=ON -D BUILD_JPEG=ON ..

4. Once that's done, enter in the terminal `make -j 4` It will probably take a while.
5. Now enter in the terminal `sudo make install`
6. Then `sudo sh -c 'echo "/usr/local/lib" > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/opencv.conf' sudo ldconfig`
7. If it worked, you should be able to `import cv2` at a python prompt and not get any errors.